# How can I load the same icon as used by MessageBox on Windows 10?

Tags: winapi, windows-10

On Windows 10 calling `LoadIcon` asking for the standard icon `IDI_INFORMATION` yields this icon:

[image]

On the other hand, calling `MessageBox` passing `IDI_INFORMATION` produces a dialog that uses this icon:

[image]

How can I obtain the second icon, if the obvious call to `LoadIcon` does not do so?

Comment: I re-wrote the question to include images to make it more clear what you refer to, and to target the question at a broader winapi audience. Accordingly I removed language specific references since they don't seem pertinent. This is really a question about winapi and not the specific language used to access the API. I trust that is reasonable.

Comment: MessageBox use `MAKEINTRESOURCE(81)` from `"imageres.dll"` - not sure that `81` resourse somehow documented. you can test this: `MSGBOXPARAMSW mbi = { 
    sizeof(mbi), 
    HWND_DESKTOP, 
    LoadLibraryEx(L"imageres", 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE),
    L"lpszText",
    L"lpszCaption",
    MB_USERICON,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(81),
   };
   MessageBoxIndirectW(&mbi);`

Comment: and compare with `MSGBOXPARAMSW mbi = { 
    sizeof(mbi), 
    HWND_DESKTOP, 
    0,
    L"lpszText",
    L"lpszCaption",
    MB_USERICON,
    IDI_INFORMATION,
   };
   MessageBoxIndirectW(&mbi);`

Comment: Icon from 'LoadLibraryEx(L"imageres", 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)' exactly what i need. Thanks.
The answer:
'LoadIconW(LoadLibraryEx('imageres', 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(81));'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like a bug in user32.dll but Windows 8 has the same issue so I guess Microsoft doesn't care.

You can get the flat icon used by `MessageBox` by calling [`SHGetStockIconInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
SHSTOCKICONINFO sii;
sii.cbSize = sizeof(sii);
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_INFO, SHGSI_ICON|SHGSI_LARGEICON, &sii)))
{
    // Use sii.hIcon here...
    DestroyIcon(sii.hIcon);
}
```

`SHGetStockIconInfo` is the documented way to get icons used in the Windows UI on Vista and later. Most of the icons come from imageres.dll but you should not assume that this is the case...

Answer (score 0):

we can try next code for test/demo

```
    MSGBOXPARAMSW mbi = { 
        sizeof(mbi), 
        HWND_DESKTOP, 
        NULL,
        L"lpszText",
        L"lpszCaption",
        MB_USERICON,
        IDI_INFORMATION
    };
    MessageBoxIndirectW(&mbi);

    if (HMODULE hmodImageRes = LoadLibraryEx(L"imageres", 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE))
    {
        mbi.hInstance = hmodImageRes;
        mbi.lpszIcon = MAKEINTRESOURCE(81);
        MessageBoxIndirectW(&mbi);
        FreeLibrary(hmodImageRes);
    }
```

first message box use standard `IDI_INFORMATION` icon [image]

when second the same icon on windows 7, and [image] on windows 8.1 and windows 10.

are *MAKEINTRESOURCE(81)* from *imageres.dll* somehow documented and be stable - i doubt

---

so obtain the second icon you can by `LoadIcon(hmodImageRes, MAKEINTRESOURCE(81))` where `HMODULE hmodImageRes = LoadLibraryEx(L"imageres", 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)` or simply `LoadLibrary(L"imageres")`

Comment: Why use implementation details when there is a documented function that gets the correct icon?

Comment: @Anders - agree, I simply look how MessageBox load icon, from which resource. however use `SHGetStockIconInfo` is much better.

Comment: I failed trying to use `SHGetStockIconInfo` and worked with you method @RbMm. Now i understand how to use it right.