# How to create a message box with new icons with VBScript or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, icons, messagebox

I have done VBScript and PowerShell message boxes since a while, but, I want to use the Windows 10 icons like these:

[image: New icons]

The only thing I want to do is to replace the Windows 7 icons to the Windows 10, as they are more modern.

Is there any way to change these icons?

Comment: This really is not a PowerShell thing/control. These icons only exist via the .Net version that is on the box.  [MessageBoxIcon Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon?view=netcore-3.1), thus if you are not running the correct .Net version on your OS, you can't do this regardless of language. What you can do is create your own msgbox (winform/wpf) form, create your own icons, from the Win10 ones and embed that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one quick code example for PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$btn = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK
$ico = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information
$Title = 'Welcome'
$Message = 'Hello world'
$Return = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $Title, $btn, $ico)
```

Output:

[image]

If I find a VBScript solution, I'll follow-up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of my comment, your query is very similar to this SO thread. Though not specific to PowerShell, the reference point is the same.

> [How can I load the same icon as used by MessageBox on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718680/how-can-i-load-the-same-icon-as-used-by-messagebox-on-windows-10)
>
> This feels like a bug in user32.dll but Windows 8 has the same issue
>   so I  guess Microsoft doesn't care.
>
> You can get the flat icon used by MessageBox by calling
>   SHGetStockIconInfo:

```
SHSTOCKICONINFO sii;
    sii.cbSize = sizeof(sii);
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_INFO, SHGSI_ICON|SHGSI_LARGEICON, &sii)))
    {
        // Use sii.hIcon here...
        DestroyIcon(sii.hIcon);
    }
```

> SHGetStockIconInfo is the documented way to get icons used in the
>   Windows UI on Vista and later. Most of the icons come from
>   imageres.dll but you should not assume that this is the case...